# I want to redirect the user to profile page after they log in

Tags: 7, users

I want to redirect the user to profile page after they log in. i tried with some modules but those could not help. i am using D7 version of drupal and tried with login modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and enable the [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module, It have the option to redirect to the specified page.

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination
>   that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site
>   (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The
>   destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible
>   to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and
>   make the destination depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to
>   provide custom conditions and destinations. It is also possible to
>   keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Comment: okay... is it possible for the logged in users to browse other menus related to their own content?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help  you,

In Drupal 7 you can use **[RULES](https://drupal.org/project/rules)** instead of using any modules only if you looking for redirection.

- Go to `admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add` to add new rule

  [image]
- Now enter the RULE name and select the event on which you want to trigger this **RULE**

  [image]
- Now its time to give some condition(if required) and to trigger the action.

  [image]
- In Action select **Page redirect**

  [image]
- Give the **redirect URL** and and check **Force redirect**

  [image]
- If the rule is not working means, there may be a other same event with higher weight. Therefore you need to increase you **rules weight**.

  [image]

Comment: Thi is for the page once they login right.. this one i got it from login destination module. after login the user will have more menu's to browse. my question is which module helps me in making settings for the menu to be update dynamically as per the user login and allow them to browse their own data

Comment: how to do this to target previous page?